# My partial local variable is not working for me. Getting an NameError Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have tried a few things and seem to be stuck. I have local var in other partials that seem to work fine.

here is my partial I want to pass through main: true

```
<%= render partial: "rental_categories", collection: @equipment_types, as: :equipment_type, main: true, cached: true %>
```

The button inside my partial I want to use the local variable

```
<%= button_to "add", pick_your_package_path(main_contact: main, equipment_type_id: equipment_type.id), method: :post,  data: { turbo: false }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

My Error is

NameError in RenterForm#new
undefined local variable or method `main' for #ActionView::Base:0x0000000004a4c0

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you need to specify the **locals** keyword with a hash of variables:

```
<%= render partial: "product", collection: @products,
       as: :item, locals: {title: "Products Page"} %>
```

See more details here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables

In your example it should look like this:

```
<%= render partial: "rental_categories", collection: @equipment_types, as: :equipment_type, locals: { main: true } %>
```

I'm not sure what is **cached: true**, so didn't put it in **locals** hash.